# “Missing parameters” error in unsubscribe confirmation

Tags: email, unsubscribe

Unsubscribe is giving an error with Drupal 7.69 and CiviCRM 5.23.4. We did not have any issues or errors during the upgrade process.

Unsubscribe links from mailings load the confirmation page correctly, with the correct partially obscured test****@domain.org. But when I fill in the email address and click Unsubscribe, it displays:

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Missing Parameters

The unsubscribe page is loaded with this URL:

https://domain.org/civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe?reset=1&jid=3590&qid=1037445&h=c38ef80808cc0140

We included the unsubscribe link in our CiviMail mailings as follows:

```
<p><a href="{action.unsubscribeUrl}" target="_blank">Unsubscribe from this list</a></p>
```

Log shows this message:

```
$Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(18) "Missing Parameters"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  object(CRM_Core_Exception)#2268 (10) {
    ["errorData":"CRM_Core_Exception":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["error_code"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["cause":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_trace":"PEAR_Exception":private]=>
    NULL
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(18) "Missing Parameters"
```

Comment: I just replicated this on a site we had pushed up to 5.24 - will raise with th  maintenance team as this seems to be a regression of some sort

Comment: I've logged an issue here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1773 as I'm still finding it is a problem on 5.24.5 - occasionally

Answer (score 1):

It appears this issue is fixed in CiviCRM 5.24.5. We upgraded and re-tested and unsubscribe now works.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in PR [#17081](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17081) and will be part of 5.24.3. You can either wait for the release or apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17081.patch).

Comment: Just noting this doesn't look like it will be reviewed / tested in time for 5.24.3 so will be in another release soon